# ModemManager debug mode

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, modem

I have a problem with modem connection on 2 from 4 of my identical laptops. I found in syslog that there is difference in this part:

**working laptop**

```
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952234] [filter]   explicit whitelist:         yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952240] [filter]   virtual devices forbidden:  yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952245] [filter]   net devices allowed:        yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952250] [filter]   cdc-wdm devices allowed:    yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952254] [filter]   tty devices:
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952259] [filter]       blacklist applied:        no
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952264] [filter]       manual scan only applied: no
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952268] [filter]       platform driver check:    yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952273] [filter]       driver check:             yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952277] [filter]       cdc-acm interface check:  yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952282] [filter]       with net check:           yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952286] [filter]       default:                  forbidden
```

**not working laptop**

```
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952234] [filter]   explicit whitelist:         yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952240] [filter]   virtual devices forbidden:  yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952245] [filter]   net devices allowed:        yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952250] [filter]   cdc-wdm devices allowed:    yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952254] [filter]   tty devices:
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952259] [filter]       blacklist applied:        yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952264] [filter]       manual scan only applied: yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952268] [filter]       platform driver check:    yes
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952273] [filter]       driver check:             no
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952277] [filter]       cdc-acm interface check:  no
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952282] [filter]       with net check:           no
ModemManager[749]: <debug> [1563287931.952286] [filter]       default:                  allowed
```

My suspicious is that somehow port on which modem is connected is blacklisted(?) How can I check this?

Comment: Can you compare the contents of /etc/udev/rules.d, /lib/udev/rules.d, /etc/udev/hwdb, /lib/udev/hwdb on both?

Comment: @grawity Thanks for the response. I just find out that on the other laptop which is working just fine the configuration is the same as in those 2 where modem has issues with connection so it seems not relevant to the problem.